# Range not selecting vba

Tags: vba, excel

My code is giving an error" 1004: Select method of Range class failed.

```
Sub AdvencedFilterNew()
'
' AdvencedFilterNew Macro
'

    Dim WsOutput As Worksheet
    Dim WsMain As Worksheet
    Dim wsScenarios As Worksheet
    Dim ScenarioIDrow As Long
    Dim ScenarioIDColumn As Long
    Dim rgn As Range
    Dim p As String
    Dim q As String

    Range("E15").Select
    Range("E17:Q350").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
    Range("E14:Q15"), Unique:=False

    Set WsOutput = Worksheets("Output")
    Set WsMain = Worksheets("Main Menu")
    Set wsScenarios = Worksheets("Scenarios.New")

    ScenarioIDrow = WsOutput.Cells.Find("Scenario ID").Row
    ScenarioIDColumn = WsOutput.Cells(ScenarioIDrow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    p = wsScenarios.Cells(ScenarioIDrow, 1).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
    q = wsScenarios.Cells(ScenarioIDrow, ScenarioIDColumn).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)

    If WsMain.Range("E15") > 0 Then

    WsOutput.Range(p, q).Select
    WsMain.Cells.Find("E15").Select
    Else
    End If

End Sub
```

So, I am selecting a range based of the address of p an q. Which are A22 and ATX22. I dont know why I can select it. it works in some other codes I use. Another issue, if the number is 4 it finds also all other numbers that contains 4, for example 1014, 1024 and so on. Can someone help me here? Thanks!

Comment: The `Range.Find` method finds cells based on their contents not address. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx  So I believe you want `WsMain.Range("E15")` where you use `WsMain.Cells.Find("E15")`

Comment: Thanks James, you are right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's because you have to `Activate` a worksheet before selecting any range of it

```
WsOutput.Range(p, q).Select
WsMain.Activate
WsMain.Cells.Find("E15").Select
```

Comment: user3598756 maybe you can help me. I want to find the E15 in WsOutput and when it finds it, i hide all the other columns. Dont know how to write it, I tried multiple times.

Comment: You are welcome. As for the other issue I'd set all `UserdRange` columns `Hidden` property to `True` and then set the found cell column `Hidden` property to `False. If you don't succeed make a new post with your coding efforts

Comment: I have to wait now 90 min. =(

Comment: @LeandroMoreira why that?

Comment: Dont know. it says that when I try again.